# How do you decide on having more than two layers to have on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, signal, layout, pcb-layers

I just started writing my bachelors thesis. I have been working as a junior hardware designer for a little less than a year now. All the boards I have designed until now have 2 layers. For my thesis I will be designing a board around the new Raspberry-Pi compute module 4, so I would like to know if I should base my design on a 4 layer board.

**1.st Question**

I see that for RF, low noise, high speed etc. applications 4 to 6-layer boards are used. I haven’t taken a lecture on the subject yet and most of my PCB knowledge is self-taught outside of the university. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain why and when to use more than 2 layers for reasons other than board complexity. If you could link maybe a book or lecture to the subject it would be even better.

**2nd Question**

I vaguely understand that for high speed boards like computer mother boards, multi-layer boards are used. Referring to my 1st question, why? Would I need to make my board multi-layered? If yes, how should I go about my layout and copper regions? Are there any mystery rules that I should take into account other than respecting the datasheets of the ICs I use?

Comment: One reason is that for many applications you want one layer to be a solid ground plane so HF currents can return underneath the trace from where they came, making for the smallest possible loop surface. On a 2 layer board that leaves only one layer left which might be too restrictive for routing complex circuits.

Comment: Apart from ground planes, modern processor boards may have 6 or more power rails which may need to be quite large and this would require power planes, driving layer count. One 16 layer board I did had 4 power planes, 4 ground planes and 8 routing layers. It also had to distribute up to 10 amps on 3 of the power rails.

Comment: @PeterSmith jeez 10A is a lot. I think I am a little too inexperienced for that level of complexity.

Comment: For high speed design rules, there are a *lot* of posts on this site from various people. The signal consulting website (the home of Dr. Howie Johnson) is also an excellent resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty broad topic, so I'll try to keep the answer general, instead of trying to answer all in detail.

First of all, some components *force* you use more than two layers. You simply **cannot** export all signals from a dense BGA chip on two layers. There's simply not enough room.

Then, some problems *force* you to use more than two layers for traces. Can't get the trace density on two layers; can't control impedance well enough (or with thin enough traces) on two layers; can't get the heat away quickly or the supply current enough without a dedicated power and ground plane... Most importantly, ground return paths **are** important, and if you need to break your ground plane because a single signal layer simply isn't able to support your circuitry (which easily happens, most schematics are not planar graphs...), then you've lost.

Then, the huge area of things that are trade-offs between complexity, cost, signal quality, ease of routing, manufacturing abilities, ... start, and you could (and will) find library shelves full of advanced PCB design methodology that explains what you can (and cannot) do on any given number of layers. For example, I don't know your salary, but not all boards are produced by the millions. If you need 10 boards of the same design, and layouting things takes you twice as long if you need to do it on two layers instead of having the freedom of four layers, well, it might simply be cheaper *and* better to do it on four, and move on to the next design.

Note that you say "4 to 6 layers are used"; but really, you can order (as far as I've personally seen) 18 layer boards (the comments show much higher layer counts, even!), so the world is slightly more complex than you think :)

Comment: I once did a 32 layer backplane that had over 2300 5Gb pairs among many other things. That did limit the number of suppliers, admittedly.

Comment: @PeterSmith you're sure you've not just tried to build the internet on a board? ;)

Comment: @PeterSmith Was that the 10mm thick basestation board? Someone on here, I forget who, made those.

Comment: When my employer Burroughs bought Sperry and we were closing the 200 ksqft factory near Bristol Tennessee, they were making 50 layer boards inhouse with vias that looked like a Remington shaver.  The liquid gold plating baths were immense like refuse dumpsters with shopping carts full of cards.  It comes down to a tradeoff between time, cost and performance specs.

Comment: Marcus : it was part of a director class (144 4x full duplex ports) Infiniband switch.

Comment: @PeterSmith ah, yeah, that's surprisingly close ;) But yeah, high-density, high-speed interconnect backplanes is where I'd look for high layer count. Actually pretty amazing that something this complex is built!

Comment: good to know :)

Comment: Also, less layers can sometimes be used when there were no board size constraints. We often had a fixed board size and we would find a way to get the required functions onto the board. More layers allow higher component density. 20-30 layers are common for satellite computers